# Отключение автообновления для конкретного свойства в Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

У меня есть объект Realm (назовем его **Message**) в этой сущности есть такое свойство как `decryptedMessageText`, которое я обновляю вручную.

через `try! realm.write {//Обновление}`

Проблема заключается в том что когда мне приходит обновление конкретного Message из сети, у меня обновляется объект целиком, и так как при инициализации у меня не существует свойства `decryptedMessageText`, объект замещает существующие значение `decryptedMessageText` на `nil`.

Возможно ли свойство `decryptedMessageText` поставить на блокировку автообновления?

Или надо ковырять метод

```
func addObject(_ object: Object) {
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(object, update: true)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример прямо из [документации Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest):

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let theDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age == 1").first
try! realm.write {
    theDog!.age = 3
}
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ, а можете более подробно расписать ответ, а то я его не очень понимаю...

Comment: @ВикторМишустин Вы пытаетесь обновить/добавить объект целиком, а вам нужно получить его из базы и поменять значение остальных полей (кроме decryptedMessageText)

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение, попробую ваш метод.

Comment: @ВикторМишустин Обновил ответ, добавил ссылку на документацию

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь, все работает!